# Given an orthonormal basis $\beta$, transformation $T$ and $T'$, show that $M_\beta(T')$ is the transpose of $M_\beta(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $\beta=\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of an inner product space $V$. Given a linear operator $T:V \rightarrow V$, define $T':V \rightarrow V$ by
$$T'(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,T(f_i) \rangle f_i$$
Show that $M_\beta(T')$ is the transpose of $M_\beta(T)$.

---

We know that for any $v \in V$, we can write $v= \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,f_i \rangle f_i$. So in this case $T′(v)=∑_{i=1}^n⟨T′(v),f_i⟩f_i=∑_{i=1}^n⟨v,T(f_i)⟩f_i$. Sadly I do not really know how we can use this to our advantage. I have thought about using the fact that $⟨T′(v),f_i⟩ = ⟨v,T(f_i)⟩$, but I do not see how I can continue. Could anyone provide me with a hint?

Comment: Inner product space = real inner product space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, isn't it true that $\langle Tv,w\rangle=\langle v,T^tw\rangle$?  This appears to make it rather trivial, since then $T'$ and $T^t$ agree on any basis.

Comment: I'm afraid that I do not follow. How does this allow us to find demonstrate the transpose part of the question?

Comment: If two linear transformations agree on a basis, then they're equal.